# Android - Reading arrays.xml

Tags: android

I have a set of preferences stored in arrays.xml, which looks similar to this:

```
<string-array name="firstname">
        <item name="1">Bob</item>
        <item name="6">Kevin</item>
        <item name="3">Peter</item>
        <item name="4">Paul</item>
        <item name="5">Simon</item>
        <item name="2">Matt</item>        
</string-array>

<string-array name="FirstnameValues">
    <item name="1">1</item>
    <item name="2">2</item>
    <item name="3">3</item>
    <item name="4">4</item>
    <item name="5">5</item>
    <item name="6">6</item>
</string-array>
```

These are used to populate ListPreference. The item stored in SharedPreferences is the name of the item; for example, for Kevin the items stored in SharedPreferences would be 6.

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String Firstname = prefs.getString("namesList", "");
```

So here, `Firstname` would give me 6, when selecting the SharedPreference key namesList for the selected item Kevin.

All I want to do is read the array.xml, so I can relate the number 6 back to Kevin. I can use `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);` but this just returns an array containing "Bob, Kevin, Peter, Paul, Simon, Matt."

It does not include the named value.

Do you have any idea on how I can get the name as well as the item for each?

Answer (score 0):

When you define you preferences in your settings.xml you can access the arrays.xml as follows (applogies for typos)

```
        <ListPreference
            android:title="FirstNameValues"
            android:summary="First Names"
            android:key="fistNamePreference"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entries="@array/firstName"
            android:entryValues="@array/fistNameValues" />
```

In your activity onCreate add

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
```

If you need more clarification please let me know. Here is an example. 
Arrays.xml

```
<string-array name="timeIntervalList">
    <item>5 seconds</item>
    <item>10 seconds</item>
    <item>30 seconds</item>
    <item>1 minute</item>
    <item>5 minutes</item>
    <item>10 minutes</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="timeIntevalValues">
    <item>5000</item>
    <item>10000</item>
    <item>30000</item>
    <item>60000</item>
    <item>300000</item>
    <item>600000</item>
</string-array>
```

settings.xml

```
<ListPreference
            android:title="Retry Interval"
            android:summary="Time interval"
            android:key="retryPeriodPref"
            android:defaultValue="5000"
            android:entries="@array/timeIntervalList"
            android:entryValues="@array/timeIntevalValues" />
```

settingsAcitivty
in onCreate call

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
```

OtherAcitivity where you wish to use the preferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getBaseContext());
timerPeriod = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("retryPeriodPref", "5000"));
```

Comment: Sorry, i should have mentioned that I have that already but thank you. I guess in a way i'm trying to access the array.xml independently of sharedpreferences. I want to simply get a number e.g. 3,  and be able to relate that to "Peter" by loading the string-array into a separate array which includes the name and the value. I read a few articles about using an TypedArray but i don't think this is the way i should be going as the results were either null or 0.

Comment: perhaps using an xml file to store this data or if there are quite a few records then sqlite perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if you can do it directly, but you could always create a wrapper class that loads both string arrays and gives you both values for any given array value.